# Creating .EXE file for Product in Advanced Installer 8.x version

Tags: java, oracle, installation, tomcat6

Our company has developed a web application based on Flex+ Spring + Hibernate. My boss wants me to make a .exe file  contains JRE, Tomcat, oracle, and our product, so that the client can just click something like installMe.exe and follow the wizard to complete the installation.

I used to deploy web application with war. Just put it under tomcat webapps folder, and start tomcat.  Now I am using Advanced Installer 8.x version,.
How to select tomcat bundle folder in Advanced Installer to create tomcat web application? , 
I am selecting

```
c:\program files\apachetomcat>\tomcat6.0\webapps
```

please help me, I am struggling for many days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the [Tomcat Web Application wizard](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/java-project-tab.html) you can simply select your Tomcat folder (`c:\program files\apachetomcat>\tomcat6.0`). This way your installer contains both Tomcat and your web application.

Comment: I added Tomcat Bundle folder with my application, but tomcat6.exe or bootstrap.exe file failed to start or stop.

Comment: I added Tomcat Bundle folder with my application, but tomcat6.exe or bootstrap.exe file failed to start or stop.it showing error "the specified service does not exist as installed service unable to open this service tomcat6".

Comment: Try contacting the Advanced Installer support team.